# Unable to start Neo4j-DB in Java

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I upgraded my Neo4j-Database from 2.2.0 to 3.0.3. I am getting the following error-message trying to start it from Java:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, F:\DLs\DB
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$203(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$$Lambda$1/1020923989.newDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
    at Neo4j.Neo4j.startServer(Neo4j.java:22)
    at countAnnotator.Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@42cdc8d0' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.storestrategy.BitmapDocumentFormat.<clinit>(BitmapDocumentFormat.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanIndexBuilder.<init>(LuceneLabelScanIndexBuilder.java:34)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanIndexBuilder.create(LuceneLabelScanIndexBuilder.java:49)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.getLuceneIndex(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newInstance(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newInstance(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 11 more
```

This is the relevant Code:

```
public class Neo4j {
    static File dir = new File("F:/DLs/DB/");
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    public void startServer(){

        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( dir )
                .setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.read_only, "true" )
                .newGraphDatabase();
        registerShutdownHook( graphDb );
    }
    }
```

And these are the Neo4j-Jars I have in my POM:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-bolt</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-lucene-index</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Sadly I have very little experience with both Maven and Neo4j and Im unable to figure out the source of the problem
I tried using the dependencies from the old DB-Version (2.2.0) but got an errormessage that "neostore.nodestore.db does not contain a store version"

I am able to run the DB without issues through the Neo4j-3.0.3-Application.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a build path issue. Are you using an IDE to compile and run, or are you doing it from the command line?

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Comment: You probably have 2 different jars of the same library in your build path. You compile against one of them, but running against the other. I remember having such issues with Lucene. Could you have two different versions of Lucene there?

Comment: There are indeed lucene-core-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar, lucene-queryparser-common-5.5.0.jar and lucene-codecs-common-5.5.0.jar in addition to the neo4j-lucene-index-3.0.3.jar in my buildpath.

I will try to remove them and check if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was indeed able to confirm that this is a buildpathissue by creating a new project without any of the other dependencies and running the code which worked fine.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
I have now found the cause of my problem:
I had the dbpedia-spotlight.jar as an external archive which also contains the lucene-jars which lead to errors when trying to start a Neo4j-Server.